# Redux - Filterable category with products - Actions & Filter

Tags: api, reactjs, pagination, redux

My state looks exactly like this:

```html
{
  categories: {
    "unique-category-id" {
      "data": {
        // All kind of data (name, description ,etc )
        "products": [
          {
            // Products that belong to this category with the current filter
          }
        ]
      },
      "readyState": "CATEGORY_FETCHED",
      "query": { // This object holds all the params that the filter allows to choose from
        "brands": [],
        "options": {
          "usb": true
          "minPrice": 200
        }
      }
    }
  
  }
}
```

This works and fetches data correctly. Now it's time to implement the filtering funcionality. I am trying to make it work like this, not sure if this is the "redux" way of doing things.

1.- On each filter on the category page we assign a click handler:

```html
<li onClick={this.toggleFilterField} key={item.VALUE}>{item.NAME}</li>
```

toggleFilterField is passed into the container via mapDispatchToProps:

```html
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    toggleFilterField: (category, filter) => {
      dispatch(toggleFilterField(category, filter))
    }
  }
}

export { CustomTagFilter };

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomTagFilter);
```

2.- My toogleFilterField should just return an action like this one:

```html
return {
  type: CHANGE_FILTER,
  category,
  filter
}
```

Then my category_reducer.js should handle this action and update the following state key

```html
state.categories[unique-category-id].query
```

Now this is OK, but now, after applying the filter to the state I would have to refetch the data from the category.

How and where do I fire a new action based on a previous action success?

Is this the correct way of handling filtered elements in redux that come from a paginated API?